# Copy from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Sub create_files_add_data(get_input)

```
lastrow1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'This is to get a count of rows in the source file.
```

' Sheet2.Range("A1:K1").Copy ' This copy of the header row works. But the copy of the data rows in the for loop doesn't work!!!

```
Dim target_workbook As Workbook
Dim target_worksheet As Worksheet
Set target_workbook = Workbooks.Add
Set target_worksheet = target_workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

       For r = 2 To lastrow1 ' This is where we use the row count to loop through all the rows to check the deptid and copy the rows
            
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & r).Value = get_input Then
            
               Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(r).Copy
                 
                       ' lastrow2 = target_worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                                  
                       ' target_worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1).Select
              
               target_worksheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' pasting here into the target workbook (but doesn't work!!!)
               
               'ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                       
            End If
            
        Next r
        
 With target_workbook
    .SaveAs filename:="C:\Users\" & get_input & ".xlsx"
     target_workbook.Close
 End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Remove the .Sheets from the set workbook, you assign the sheet in the next line.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. Still gives me the same error.

Comment: Then the string is probably not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the workbook is already open, you access the workbook from the `workbooks`-collection by name, but without path.

```
target_file = get_input & ".xlsx"
Set target_workbook = Workbooks(target_file)
```

If you want to open the workbook, you need to use the `Open`-method and specify the full path:

```
target_file = "C:\Users\" & bu_to_process & "\" & get_input & ".xlsx"
Set target_workbook = Workbooks.Open(target_file)
```

To create a brand new workbook, use the `Add`-method to create it and the `SaveAs`-method to save:

```
target_file = "C:\Users\" & bu_to_process & "\" & get_input & ".xlsx"
Set target_workbook = Workbooks.Add
' (do your work here)
' ...
target_workbook.SaveAs target_workbook, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

You can save it as CSV also, however, the file extension should reflect the file type:

```
target_file = "C:\Users\" & bu_to_process & "\" & get_input & ".csv"
target_workbook.SaveAs target_workbook, xlCSV
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, I get below if you can suggest why this would happen:

Run-time error '1004'

Excel cannot open the file 'xxx.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: I see that you are creating an empty text file first - I guess that's the problem. You cannot open an empty text file as Excel file. Instead, create a new workbook and save it with the correct name. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try and update here if it worked out.

Comment: FunThomas - Thanks for your inputs. I got past the errors. Now, the rows are not getting copied from my source file to the newly created file. Only the header row is copying. Can you please check where I'm going wrong? I have updated with the new code. Thanks much.

Comment: Just wanted to provide an update that copy to a secondary workbook worked. I was using the wrong variable which wasn't calling copy. Thanks for the inputs and your time.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Just accept the answer so that others see its answered